# How to solve (NaN error) when given column specific name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-import, read.csv

I have many text files include data as follow:

```
350.0   2.1021    0.0000   1.4769    0.0000
357.0   2.0970    0.0000   1.4758    0.0000
364.0   2.0920    0.0000   1.4747    0.0000
371.0   2.0874    0.0000   1.4737    0.0000
```

I need to give each column a specific name (Ex:a,b,c,d,e)

```
 a         b        c         d         e
350.0   2.1021    0.0000   1.4769    0.0000
357.0   2.0970    0.0000   1.4758    0.0000
364.0   2.0920    0.0000   1.4747    0.0000
371.0   2.0874    0.0000   1.4737    0.0000
```

After that I will start to split columns and use them separately
I wrote this code

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

input_files = glob.glob('input/*.txt')    
for file_name in input_files:
     data = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    
     columns_list = ["a", "b", "c","d", "e"]
     data_list = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns_list)
     print(data_list)
```

the result is

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can define columns while reading from CSV file.

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_name, names=columns_list)
```

Comment: It gives me this

                                                                          a   b   c   d   e
0    350.0   2.1021    0.0000   1.4769    0.0000 NaN NaN NaN NaN